# Would installing different versions of libssl cause problems?

Tags: software-installation, debian, crunchbang

I am trying to install testing version of [Spotify on Debian](https://www.spotify.com/us/download/previews/). It's a testing version and they say it's for Debian Squeeze, my Crunchbang *(64 bit)* is based on Debian Wheezy, but I'm trying to install it anyway.

It says:

```
% sudo apt-get install spotify-client   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 spotify-client : Depends: libssl0.9.8 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
% sudo apt-get install spotify-client   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 spotify-client : Depends: libssl0.9.8 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

In synaptic manager i see that I have `libssl1.0.0`. So is it possible to install `libssl0.9.8`? And would that cause any problems or conflicts between the versions installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [HowTo](http://support.rstudio.org/help/kb/advanced/installing-openssl-098-on-debian-7-wheezy), that explains it.

Just download the deb file with

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-4squeeze14_amd64.deb
```

and run

```
sudo dpkg -i libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-4squeeze14_amd64.deb
```

It should be no problem.

Comment: It is good that it worked. But in the future please don't add comments with just thank you. The comments should only be used to add value to the answer and you're welcome. :)